# need click to clipboard button on my site

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm using this code

```
<!-- The text field -->
<input type="text" value="[gamipress_referral_url]" id="myInput">

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

What I want to happen is, if I click on copy text button then copy the generated link which is I used `[shortcode]` on input type.

Comment: Please arrange the code to be legible.

Comment: Your JS isn't wrapped in a `<script>` tag.  You should also move your JS to a different file, properly enqueue it, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.